# How to iterate over the matched groups of a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following case that does not work the way I expect, and, I am doing something wrong, but I cannot find out what that is. The script matches the four letter words within a sentence. I want to find a way to iterate over the matched groups.

```
x = "This is a statement with four letter words like this"
result = x.match /(\b\w{4}\b)/
=> #<MatchData "This" 1:"This">
```

Unfortunately, `$1` contains `"This"`, but this is all I get. `$2` should contain `"with"` but it is `nil`. What am I doing wrong? Why is `$2` `nil`? Why is `$n` with `n>=2` nil?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are doing, but remember that regexp is not always the right tool for the job. You can also try something like x.split.select{|x| x.size == 4}

Comment: @hirolau: Good point (the one about not always using regexps). Here, it depends on the definition of "word". `split` will not play nice with punctuation -- unless you use a regexp as delimiter ;-)

Comment: True, yes the code works if you use the delimiter /\W+/ but then the original code is easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your regexp matches just once and contains just one capture group.

You probably want:

```
x.scan /\b\w{4}\b/
```

which will give you an array of all matches.

`$1`, `$2` ... are set to the groups in a single match of the regexp, e.g.

```
x.match(/(\b\w{4}\b).*(\b\w{4}\b)/)
```

sets `$1` to `'This'` and `$2` to `'this'`.

The groups can also be accessed through `$~[1]`, `$~[2]`, ... or `Regexp.last_match[1]` ...